# How to update a specific row with column value change in android sqlite

Tags: android, sql-update, android-sqlite, shopping-cart

I am working on shopping cart module. I want to add the cart to my database when i am pressing cart button the scenario is i have two product in my detail page one is ebook and another one is pbook. If i press either one of them i need to create a row based on pro , name and auto increment key. Then if i press second cart button i need to update the same row once again by checking the pro or name value existence. Below is how i created the database. Can anyone help me how to update the row if the value exists in database column.

```
   //////From activity

     AddCartHelper databaseHelper=new AddCartHelper(WYWProductDetail.this);
     databaseHelper.saveCategoryRecord(wyw_pro_id,wyw_book_name);


    ////Helper Class


        public class AddCartHelper {
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "category.db";
private static final String TABLE_NAME = "tbcategory";
public static final String CATEGORY_COLUMN_ID = "_id";
public static final String CATEGORY_COLUMN_PRO = "pro";
public static final String CATEGORY_COLUMN_NAME = "name";
Category openHelper;
private SQLiteDatabase database;
ContentValues contentValues;
String name_id;
public AddCartHelper(Context context) {
    openHelper = new Category(context);
    database = openHelper.getWritableDatabase();

}

public void saveCategoryRecord(String name, String pro) {

    contentValues = new ContentValues();

    contentValues.put(CATEGORY_COLUMN_PRO, pro);
    contentValues.put(CATEGORY_COLUMN_NAME, name);
    if(!name.equals(contentValues.get(CATEGORY_COLUMN_NAME))) {

    } else {
        database.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);
        database.close();
    }
    }

public Cursor getTimeRecordList() {
    return database.rawQuery("select * from " + TABLE_NAME, null);
    }
private class Category extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public Category(Context context) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "( "
                    + CATEGORY_COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
                    + CATEGORY_COLUMN_PRO + " TEXT, "
                    + CATEGORY_COLUMN_NAME + " TEXT )" );   
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS"+ TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);
    }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will update all rows whose Name = oldName with newName.

```
public int updateAllName(String oldName, String newName) {
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(CATEGORY_COLUMN_NAME, newName);
    return Db.update(TABLE_NAME, values, CATEGORY_COLUMN_NAME + " = '" + oldName + "'", null);
}
```

This will update all rows whose Pro = oldPro with newPro

```
public int updateAllPro(String oldPro, String newPro) {
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(CATEGORY_COLUMN_PRO, newPro);
    return Db.update(TABLE_NAME, values, CATEGORY_COLUMN_PRO + " = '" + oldPro + "'", null);
}
```

Comment: This is just one example of how to change a table row. You need to adapt it to your needs and call it when necessary. It is a starting point for you to try to do the rest by yourself. After that, if you need more help makes us know

Comment: It should probably be `CATEGORY_COLUMN_NAME + " = '" + oldName + "'"` and `CATEGORY_COLUMN_PRO + " = '" + oldPro + "'"` ;)